# Remove after certain number in Double

Tags: swift, double, precision

I'm using a loop to generate some Doubles to append to an array, the code itself is fine and working but the actual numbers have precision far more than I need.

For example, if a number it generates is `2.3632731` I only need the `2.3` part with no rounding. Is there a way using Swift to simply cut off after that one decimal place?

Comment: Only the string representation. If you really need 2.3 as a numeric type you should use `Decimal` instead of `Double`

Comment: I am not sure if it would work for every single case but you can try `modf(value * 10).0 / 10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just cast to an Int to truncate the decimal part and then back.

```
let x = 2.363271
let y = Double(Int(x * 10)) / 10.0
```

Comment: why not simply `modf(x * 10).0 / 10`?

Comment: @LeoDabus your version is marginally slower and subjectively no clearer. I see no benefits to using it in this situation.

Comment: "My" version is how you should do it. "Your" version is like a hack. If there is a method exactly for this purpose you should use it.

Comment: While your version may achieve the same result, a cast from a Double to an Int "cuts off the remainder" like OP asked. When you work, you have many tools at your disposal and it's your duty to understand the purpose of each and determine the best to use to get the job done. Sometimes when I work around the house, I use the back of my drill to drive a drywall anchor into wall even though a hammer is more suitable. If you want to use modf, nobody will stop you. However, I will continue to do it the way I suggested. My version is no more of a hack than yours is.

Comment: First of all I would never use `modf` to "remove" fraction digits precision. All you need is to use `NumberFormatter` to display it to the user. Why would you care about it? If the intent is to preserve fraction digits precision you better work with Decimal and use the string initializer.

Comment: I never said your answer is wrong. Besides the fact that what is being asked is already non sense. IMO going from floating point to integer and back to floating point doesn't make any sense. That's all. If your answer is good or not time will tell. Lets see how many up votes this will get in the long run